# How to install/import new version of numpy (1.9) on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: numpy

can anybody help me to install / import new version of numpy? 
I am running Ubuntu 12.04 which uses by default numpy 1.6 but I need to install numpy 1.8+ as a requirement of aother package.

I have downloaded numpy 1.9.1 and install it with standard instructions: python setup.py install --user (tried also pip install numpy --upgrade). The new version is installed in.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy.

I have set the path to the new locally installed numpy by: 
export PYTHONPATH="/home/lukas/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy"

Run python and check if the path is there visible: 
import sys
sys.path
'/home/lukas/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy'

Then import numpy and check the version by numpy.version.version, which says

'1.6.1'

Evidently, it imported the original numpy version. How can I change it so the python import the new, locally installed, version?

Thanks!
Lukas